# Data Recovery software for the SD 722

Tags: data, recovery, for, sd722

Hi,

I am searching for links to getting the data recovery software for the SD722. The service providers here in South Africa are not being very helpful and since we are using the recorders at an educational institute, my experience has been that we need the software to ensure that things do not got belly up.

Also, what advice do you guys have on making sure that the machines run properly. We have 9 machines and about 50 odd students using them which means that not everyone will be treating the machines the same way. In the past, we used the Nagra LB and we had serious problems with the internal hard drives losing data and the drives becoming infected with viruses. This is due to the students not formatting their machines after they have dumped their sounds and also dumping their sounds on to computers that were infected. It is a serious problem and some people lost their sounds due to the Nagras corrupt drives. What can be done to ensure that the machines maintain stability and what can be done to prevent data loss.

I hope my inquiry is clear.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

the 722 means you can record to a CF card AND hard drive at the same time - so that offers some data security, ie make them primarily use CF cards & keep the HD as a safety clone....

Answer (score 2):

Try Sandisk's RescuePRO and/or Recuva.

I agree with Tim though. When you're using a 722, I would just ask the students to only pull their files from the CF cards and not connect directly to the 722.

Answer (score 0):

I second RescuePRO. Had a similar problem when I hired an LB out last year. Connected it to my HD then it all when a bit nuts! Managed to get most of it back with the data recovery software but some tracks were damaged with chunks of noise.